# Did Hitler say "Who speaks today of the extermination of the Armenians?"

Tags: quotes, adolf-hitler

This article [claims](http://www.meforum.org/meq/pdfs/3434.pdf) that just a week before the September 1, 1939 invasion of Poland, Hitler asked:

> Who speaks today of the extermination of the Armenians?

Did Hitler say this quote or something along those lines?

This question is not about the actual genocide, but only whether Hitler said this quote or not?

Note: Wikipedia has [a section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obersalzberg_Speech#The_Armenian_quote) discussing this.

Comment: Given Wikipedia has a discussion about the controversy around the quote, what sort of answer would it take to convince you that the quote is accurate or inaccurate?

Comment: @Oddthinking, first I don't assume that Wikipedia is necessarily covering all the relevant sources.  Maybe it is, maybe it isn't.

Second, maybe someone here can add to the analysis.  For example, look at the backgrounds of the historians and their take on [Functionalism versus intentionalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functionalism_versus_intentionalism) and how that may have affected their conclusions).

Comment: The same argument could apply to any answer here, and the Wikipedia page is more likely to attract relevant experts. (Where we beat Wikipedia, it is because we are stricter on the need for references. The Wikipedia page seems reasonably referenced.) So, again, what would it take to convince you that *this* answer is definitive, over the similar arguments on Wikipedia? I suggest this will be almost impossible to answer.